# PDF manipulating framework/API

Tags: pdf, api, framework

Could please someone recommend a really solid framework or API for manipulating PDF -- precise rendering (including crop), color management, layers etc. Free or commercial.

This is for design review tool that visualizes pdf files and allows to annotate it etc.

I know, Adobe PDF Library by Datalogic is perfect, but incredibly expensive, no way.

I have tried dozens of available frameworks like Aspose, Ghostscript, PDFium, Poppler, Apple Core Graphics etc and still not happy.

- The biggest issue is color rendering. They all produce more or less different colors, compared to Adobe's tools. When different color modes are in the same file it's a disaster (like RGB and CMYK).
- Performance. Rendering average PDF A4 with DPI 600 could take minutes, sometimes tens of minutes. Datalogics Adobe PDF Library can render a crop in a virtually
  constant time, not dependent on DPI, this allows to implement fast
  zooming. No one else seems able to do it.

Probably I missed something...

Thank you!